# unable to commit pom.xml in intellij idea / svn

Tags: java, maven, svn, intellij-idea, pom.xml

when I try to commit pom.xml in the intellij idea, it says "no changes in svn". But it's very weird when I compare it with the same repository version, I can see the changes with the svn. I cleaned up(SVN Cleanup) the project, updated the project and refreshed file status but unfortunately I am still not able to commit the file. It makes me mad ? Do you know a way to fix it ?

Regards
Alper

Comment: Please check that the correct project root is mapped to Subversion in VCS settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not the best way, but sometimes rather than wasting time with solving that kind of problem, approach it in a different way. I suggest you,

1. Commit your other files, then delete your local workspace.
2. After that pull your codes from your repository with a clean start.
3. Finally, make changes in that pom file and you will definitely see your changes now.

Don't waste time with that, just do this and spend your time with your work imho.

Btw I encountered similar problem when I was using TFS some time ago. It turned out to be in TFS one can work on files locally without TFS realising it. I wasted too much time solving it. SVN may have similar ability too.